# scanning from file to a structure

Tags: c

having problem when assigning a value from the array  to the object member
here is my code

it is segmentation error but i cant see why
I can't get any msg from the compile
the program only crashes
thanks

```
FILE * openRead(char fName[]);
int setArray(FILE *fp, struct salesPerson* sRec[]);
#define EMPLOYEES 8

int main(){

FILE *fp=openRead("sales.dat");
struct salesPerson *instance[EMPLOYEES];
setArray(fp,instance);

return 0;

}

FILE * openRead(char fName[]){  //READS
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen(fName,"r");
if ((fp != NULL)){
   // printf("return succ");
    return fp;
}else{
    return 0;
}
}

int setArray(FILE *fp, struct salesPerson* sRec[]){

int  i,num[30],lpay[30];
char fname[30][30];
char lname[30][30];
double amount[30];
for (i=0;i<=EMPLOYEES;i++){
//while (!feof(fp)){
    if(fscanf(fp,"%d:%[^:]:%[^:]:%d:%lf",&num[i],lname[i],fname[i],&lpay[i],&amount[i]) != EOF){

    strcpy(sRec[i]->lastName,lname[i]);
    //strcpy(sRec[i]->firstName,fname);
    //sRec[i]->salesLevel=*lpay;
    //sRec[i]->salesAmount=amount;
    //printf("%s",sRec[i]->lastName);
    //if(fscanf(fp,"%d:%[^:]:%[^:]:%d :%f",&num,fname,lname,&payl,&amount) != EOF){

    printf("%s \n",fname[i]);
 }
    }
 return i;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pointers do not point somewhere valid.

```
struct salesPerson *instance[EMPLOYEES];
setArray(fp,instance);
```

Where is `instance[0]` (and all the other pointers) pointing to?

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for your pointers before writing something to it.Like

```
instance[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct salesPerson));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0;i<EMPLOYEES;i++){// "<=" should be "<" 
    if(fscanf(fp,"%d:%[^:]:%[^:]:%d:%lf",&num[i],lname[i],fname[i],&lpay[i],&amount[i]) != EOF){
        sRec[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct salesPerson));//allocate structure
        strcpy(sRec[i]->lastName,lname[i]);
        //set to member of sRec ... 
    } else 
        break;
}
```